# PC keeps restarting after installing new GPU even when old GPU is out in

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, bios, hardware-failure

I've replaced an old graphics card with a new one and after some problems I've made it work for one time with both cards being in simultaneously. Then I turned off the PC to take out the old graphic card and turned it on again.

Since then whenever I turn it on it just keeps restarting without showing even BIOS. The DVD drive does make a noise at the beginning. Time before restart is something about 18 seconds currently.

Detailed steps as far as I remember:

1. Removed old card, put in new card, didn't see anything
2. Put in old card additionally to try to configure system to work with the new card. I don't know when but somewhere at step 1 or 2 i already had the restarting problem except that with one restart it suddenly worked
3. Installed driver for new GPU and then it worked
4. Turned PC off, removed old GPU and turned on again
5. PC just keeps restarting
6. Tried to put old one in again additionally, just like it worked before but didn't work either
7. Tried other configurations, including the original configuration before I got the new card, all just made the PC restart repeatedly

I've also tried to

- reset the BIOS by unplugging and removing the BIOS battery for a few minutes
- remove half of the RAM
- disconnect the SSD
- start without GPU (although I'm not sure if my motherboard supports that)

but that didn't change anything.

Other changes I've made before adding the new GPU which didn't cause any serious problems:

- Replaced an SSD
- Installed windows on that SSD

Only problem I had at that point was that windows showed a too low resolution even though graphics card and monitor supported more but I didn't care about that at that point because I'd put in the new graphics card anyway

I have a suspicion that the PSU might be too weak for the new graphics card but that shouldn't be relevant if I only have the old one in, plus it did work one time.

Any ideas on what might be the problem or what I can check?

I'm just perplexed that just going back to the configuration that used to work doesn't work anymore. For now I'd be happy if I'd just get the old configuration working

Specifications:

- PSU: Thermaltake Berlin 630 W
- Motherboard: Gigabyte X99-UD4
- Intel Core i7-5820k @ 3.3GHz x 12
- 16 GB RAM as 4x 4GB DDR4
- old GPU: EN210 SILENT/DI/1GD3(LP)
- new GPU: MSI Radeon RX 580 Armor OC 8GB
- SSD has 1 TB, only Windows on it, no other data
- old SSD had 500 GB with Ubuntu on it but that wasn't connected ever since I've connected the new SSD
- DVD drive

There are no other cards or drives in the PC

Comment: What's the rest of your hardware config (CPU or SoC, integrated graphics, how much RAM, how much free space on the SSD, everything)?

Comment: Could be you have a compatibility problem between your new GPU and your CPU, depending on the mobo you have: your CPU only supports x16 x8 x4 graphics in PCIe. A modern 8GB GPU will most likely only support x16 x16. To be checked with the exact mobo you have, but that could be the reason why it booted with both the old and (most probably non working) new GPU, and failed to boot with only the new one.

Comment: Is it enough now?

Comment: Do you have a motherboard speaker connected? Sometimes if the M/B can't start, it will use that to beep a code indicating the problem. Your PC case might have come with one - many people don't fit it. See page 31 of the [motherboard manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-x99-ud4_e.pdf) for where to attach it.

Comment: I have a headphones connected to the front which worked before the upgrade, it doesn't make a sound when restarting. I'm not sure if that also works for the beep at boot time

Comment: @JimmyT. I would not expect the headphone output to be working that early in the boot process. You can get a motherboard speaker for less than $2 on ebay and elsewhere, but if you assembled the PC yourself then there might be one in the accessories box that came with the case.